# How to move annotation in space once it has been drawn?

Tags: annotation

Is there a way to move (grab) annotation once it has been drawn? In all windows where Annotations work in the tools panel there are only options to Annotate, Annotate Line, Annotate Polygon and Annotate Erase, but no option to Annotate grab/move or anything similar. It seems quite obvious to me that such option should exist somewhere, but does it in fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with standard tools, you should use a Grease Pencil object instead.